# Jquery DataTables Persistent Primary Sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Is there a way in jquery DataTables 1.10.1 to always do a primary sort on a hidden column regardless of what visible columns the user clicks to sort on?

The spec is to always have primary sort on a numeric `groupsortkey` in asc order.
The aim is to always have rows with the same `groupsortkey` clustered together and not dispersed regardless of what other visible column the user wants to sort on.

In the snippet below, the element with `id="taskViewer"` is a valid html table with ten columns, the first of which will be hidden and serve as the `groupsortkey`.

```
 var taskViewer = $("#taskViewer").dataTable({
                "columnDefs": [{
                    "targets": [0],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": false }],
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [orderFixed](http://datatables.net/reference/option/orderFixed) option.  It allows you to do pre or post user sorting.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "orderFixed": {
        "pre": [ 0, 'asc' ]
    }
} );
```

In this scenario, the 0 column will be the primary sort and then the user selected sort is secondary.